# Cauchy Integral Formula/Continuous function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $C(z,r)$ denote the circle centered at $z$ with radius $r$. Let $f$ be a continuous function defined on a domain $D$. For $n=1,2$  and each $z \in D$ let

$A_n(z)=\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{1}{2\pi ir^n} \int_{C(z,r)} f(\zeta) d\zeta$ if the limit exists.

Show that if $f$ is continuous on $D$, then $A_1(z)=0$ for each $z\in D$

$\textbf{My Attempt:}$

Let $\gamma(t)=z+re^{i\theta}$
Then $\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{1}{2\pi ir^n} \int_{C(z,r)} f(\zeta) d\zeta=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(z+re^{i\theta})e^{i\theta}$.

I am very stuck on what to do from here, I somehow need to show that the limit evaluates to zero. I am not sure if I can use any primitive of $f$ since $f$ is not necessarily analytic, we only know it is continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key intuitive insight is that you should be thinking of $f$ as essentially constant near $z$.  In other words, integrating $f(\zeta)$ should not be too different from integrating $f(z)$ around the small loop.  If this were real analysis, this would give us something like $2\pi f(z)$, but since it is a complex integral the directions $d\zeta$ all conspire to cancel out (I am just saying that $\int 1 d\zeta = 0$).

The above is nothing rigorous, but it should give us some clue as to how to proceed.  We should try to compare the integral of $f(\zeta)$ to the integral of $f(z)$.

$$\int_{C(z,r)} f(\zeta) d\zeta = \int_{C(z,r)} f(\zeta)-f(z) d\zeta$$

since $f(z)$ is constant with respect to $\zeta$.

So $$\left| \int_{C(z,r)} f(\zeta) d\zeta \right|= \left|\int_{C(z,r)} f(\zeta)-f(z) d\zeta\right|$$

$$= \left| r\int_0^{2\pi} f(z+re^{i\theta}) -f(z) d\theta \right|$$

$$\leq r \int_0^{2\pi}\left| f(z+re^{i\theta}) - f(z)\right| d\theta$$

Do you see how to take it from here?

Comment: Isn't it funny how we essentially do nothing (just subtract 0), and yet it makes all the difference in the world?

Comment: Thank you Steven! Your answer is useful as it is very easy to comprehend.As you had pointed out we simply subtract zero. I also really appreciate the intuition you have given as I had not thought about the problem in such a way.